# B+ tree node sizing

Tags: database, theory, couchdb, b-tree

I'm planning on writing a simple key/value store with a file architecture similar to CouchDB, i.e. an append-only b+tree.

I've read everything I can find on B+trees and also everything I can find on CouchDB's internals, but I haven't had time to work my way through the source code (being in a very different language makes it a special project in its own right).

So I have a question about the sizing the of B+tree nodes which is: **given key-length is variable, is it better to keep the nodes the same length (in bytes) or is it better to give them the same number of keys/child-pointers regardless of how big they become?**

I realise that in conventional databases the B+tree nodes are kept at a fixed length in bytes (e.g. 8K) because space in the data files is managed in fixed size pages. But in an append-only file scheme where the documents can be any length and the updated tree nodes are written after, there seems to be no advantage to having a fixed-size node.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The goal of a b-tree is to minimize the number of disk accesses. If the file system cluster size is 4k, then the ideal size for the nodes is 4k. Also, the nodes should be properly aligned. A misaligned node will cause two clusters to be read, reducing performance.

With a log based storage scheme, choosing a 4k node size is probably the worst choice unless gaps are created in the log to improve alignment. Otherwise, 99.98% of the time one node is stored on two clusters. With a 2k node size, the odds of this happening are just under 50%. However, there's a problem with a small node size: average height of the b-tree is increased and the time spent reading a disk cluster is not fully utilized.

Larger node sizes reduce the height of the tree, but they too increase the number of disk accesses. Larger nodes also increase the overhead of maintaining the entries within the node. Imagine a b-tree where the node size is large enough to encapsulate the entire database. You have to embed a better data structure within the node itself, perhaps another b-tree?

I spent some time prototyping a b-tree implementation over an append-only log format and eventually rejected the concept altogether. To compensate for performance losses due to node/cluster misalignment, you need to have a very large cache. A more traditional storage approach can make better use of the RAM.

The final blow was when I evaluated the performance of randomly-ordered inserts. This kills performance of any disk-backed storage system, but log based formats suffer much more. A write of even the smallest entry forces several nodes to be written to the log, and the internal nodes are invalidated shortly after being written. As a result, the log rapidly fills up with garbage.

BerkeleyDB-JE (BDB-JE) is also log based, and I studied its performance characteristics too. It suffers the same problem that my prototype did -- rapid accumulation of garbage. BDB-JE has several "cleaner" threads which re-append surviving records to the log, but the random order is preserved. As a result, the new "clean" records have already created log files full of garbage. The overall performance of the system degrades to the point that the only thing running is the cleaner, and it's hogging all system resources.

Log based formats are very attractive because one can quickly implement a robust database. The Achilles heel is the cleaner, which is non-trivial. Caching strategies are also tricky to get right.